# Add a reference for each day in a date range

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

**** updated as I missed a valuable bit of information that the date records are not unique in the dataset.****

I'm sure this is straightforward but I can't figure out how to do this without a manual lookup table of individual dates and references.

I have a table of dates (y/m/d) and several date ranges.

My dates look like this:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2022/4/11 |
| 2022/4/12 |
| 2022/4/13 |
| 2022/4/13 |
| 2022/4/13 |
| 2022/4/13 |
| 2022/4/13 |
| 2022/4/14 |
| 2022/4/14 |
| 2022/4/14 |
| 2022/4/15 |
| 2022/4/16 |
| 2022/4/16 |
| 2022/4/16 |

My date range looks like this:

| Start.date | Completed.date |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/4/13 | 2022/4/16 |

How do I add a column to show the date series? My output should look like:

| Date | Date.number |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/4/11 |  |
| 2022/4/12 |  |
| 2022/4/13 | 1 |
| 2022/4/13 | 1 |
| 2022/4/13 | 1 |
| 2022/4/13 | 1 |
| 2022/4/13 | 1 |
| 2022/4/14 | 2 |
| 2022/4/14 | 2 |
| 2022/4/14 | 2 |
| 2022/4/15 | 3 |
| 2022/4/16 | 4 |
| 2022/4/16 | 4 |
| 2022/4/16 | 4 |
| 2022/4/17 |  |
| 2022/4/17 |  |
| 2022/4/18 |  |

Advanced thanks for any help.

Code for tables:

```
Date.range <- structure(list(Start.date = "2022/4/13", Completed.date = "2022/4/16"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L))

Date <- structure(list(Date = c("2022/4/11", "2022/4/12", "2022/4/13", 
                                 "2022/4/14", "2022/4/14","2022/4/14","2022/4/15", "2022/4/16","2022/4/16","2022/4/16",
                                 "2022/4/17","2022/4/17","2022/4/18")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Date.range <- structure(list(Start.date = "2022/4/13", Completed.date = "2022/4/16"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L))

Date <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2022/4/11","2022/4/12","2022/4/13","2022/4/13",
           "2022/4/13","2022/4/13","2022/4/13","2022/4/14",
           "2022/4/14","2022/4/14","2022/4/15","2022/4/16",
           "2022/4/16","2022/4/16"))

Date %>% 
  mutate(Day.number = ymd(Date) >= ymd(Date.range$Start.date) & ymd(Date) <= ymd(Date.range$Completed.date)) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(Day.number = if_else(Day.number, cur_group_id(), NA_integer_)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(Day.number = Day.number - min(Day.number, na.rm = T) + 1)

#> # A tibble: 14 × 2
#>    Date      Day.number
#>    <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 2022/4/11         NA
#>  2 2022/4/12         NA
#>  3 2022/4/13          1
#>  4 2022/4/13          1
#>  5 2022/4/13          1
#>  6 2022/4/13          1
#>  7 2022/4/13          1
#>  8 2022/4/14          2
#>  9 2022/4/14          2
#> 10 2022/4/14          2
#> 11 2022/4/15          3
#> 12 2022/4/16          4
#> 13 2022/4/16          4
#> 14 2022/4/16          4
```

Comment: Wow @PaulS you're super fast. Thanks for this I couldnt get cumsum to work earlier! Trying it now

Comment: Thanks PaulS, I realised my code example missed a core bit of information.  The same date can be across multiple rows.

Comment: @Keelin: I have updated my solution accordingly. I hope that meets your needs.

Comment: Thank-you so much @PaulS, I also figured out how to adapt it to look up a range of date range values.  Appreciate this very much.